# How to enforce that construction is always through a certain method?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++14, object-construction

I have some third-party abstract base class

```
struct foo
{
    virtual foo*job() = 0;
    ...
    static void* make_space(size_t sizeofDerived);
};
```

which I cannot alter. Objects of type `foo` (and all derived classes) must only be created/constructed using [placement-new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) into the memory returned by `foo::make_space()`,
because ordinary construction, as in

```
derived_from_foo z;                 // or
auto p = new derived_from_foo();
```

may cause undesired problems (corrupting memory, depending on the compiler, as I found out eventually). So my question: how can I write/design a derived class

```
struct bar  // still abstract, since foo::job() is not provided
  : foo
{
    ...
    template<typename Derived, typename...Args>
    static Derived* create(Args&&...args)
    {
        return ::new(foo::make_space(sizeof(Derived)))
            Derived(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

such that construction of objects of type `bar` *or any type derived from `bar`* by any other means than through `bar::create()` fails at (i) compilation or (ii, less ideal) at run-time?

Comment: Private constructor in `bar` wasn't enough?

Comment: You can employ tricks, for sure. But it doesn't make it impossible. Only less likely. Whatever you do, it won't stop a determined person who can simply write `::new derived_from_foo()`.

Comment: @Ext3h If `bar` has only `private` constructors, how can you derive from `bar`?

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact enforce it, at a price.

Consider this class:

```
  class A
  {
      public:
          class Tag
          {
              public:
                  Tag(const Tag&) = default;
                  Tag(Tag&&) = default;
              private:
                  Tag() {}
                  friend class A;
          };

          A(Tag, int a, char b) : a(a), b(b) {}
          int a;
          char b;

          template<typename T, typename ... Params>
          static T* make(Params&& ... params)
          {
              return new T(Tag(), std::forward<Params>(params)...);
          }
  };
```

Its constructor requires a `Tag` parameter, but you cannot make a `Tag`, it's got a private constructor. You can derive from `A`, but you cannot directly create objects of a derived class either: it needs to pass a `Tag` to its parent constructor, and you cannot make one.

So the only way to create an object of `A` or a derived class is by calling `A::make`.

---

Well there is still a way to cheat

```
class B : public A
{
    public:
        B(Tag t, double q) : A(t, 42, 'z'), q(q) {
           // cheating:
           B* other = new B(t, 3.14);
        }
        double q;
};
```

If this bothers you, you still can enforce correctness at run-time by making `Tag` non-reusable à la `std::unique_ptr`. Remove the copy ctor, throw in a private bool flag that you set on construction and clear on move-out, and check it inside `make`.